# How to iterate custom inner array object with handlebars?

Tags: meteor, iteration, handlebars.js

I am trying to iterate a custom inner array object "choices". See below example, "choices" can have different number of objects inside.

```
{
       _id:  1,
"question": "a",
"choices": [
           {"a" : 1},
           {"b" : "blablabla"},
           {"c" : 128},
           {"d" : "blebleble"}
          ],
  "answer": "b",
  "points": "10"
},
{
       _id:  10,
"question": "j",
"choices": [
           {"a" : 10},
           {"b" : "blablabla"}
          ],
  "answer": "b",
  "points": "10"
}
```

I am able to display "question", "answer", "points".

This is the template I am using in main.html

```
  <template name="question">
  <button>Click Me</button>
  {{#with object}}
      {{question}}
      {{#each choices}}
        ??
      {{/each}}
      {{answer}}
      {{points}}
  {{/with}}
  </template>
```

Any help is appreciated. If you guys need more info please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to mend your data structure a bit as below

```
choices:[
          {key:"a",value:1},
          {key:"b",value:"bla"},
          {key:"c",value:"blabla"},
          {key:"d",value:"blablabla"}
        ]
```

Now in your template

```
{{#each choices}}
<span>Your choice is {{key}}.{{value}}</span>
{{/each}}
```

It should help
Thank you

Comment: That's the answer I was looking for. Thanks!